# Openstack Monitoring

Tags: openstack, nagios

I have done deployment using openstack-ansible community playbook and integrated with nagios (seperate nagios-server) for service monitoring. All my service inside containers run in private IP so I got stuck in position how to monitor service running inside container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ceilometer to monitor services, if your goal is to create alarms and auto-scale your stacks.

If you want to have a dashboard with some of the applications then it is user-side monitoring. In this case there are many tools like datadog.